# About Struts2. in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I already imported the jar package into my ***project structure***, and also imported ***File Sets*** into my ***project structure*** Modules. However, the Struts.xml can't find struts–default? How can I fix this?

Comment: Please, verify that your struts.xml is in the same fileset as struts-default.xml

Comment: @ervidio yes, only one fileset int Modules.